# CREATE TABLE AS SELECT

Tags: impala

I am trying a simple `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` in Impala 2.3.0 and it doesn't seem to work.

`CREATE TABLE clone_of_t1 AS SELECT * FROM t1;`

> Query: create TABLE clone_of_t1 AS SELECT * FROM t1  ERROR:
>   AnalysisException: testdb CAUSED BY: NoSuchObjectException: testdb

Are there any special options required for this to work?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you running your query?! JDBC?! HUE?! impala-shell?!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the database **testdb** doesn't exist. You could look your JDBC url to check if the database name is correct, it should be similar to this:

```
jdbc:impala://{host}:{port}/{database}
```